# Functions are not valid as a React Child warning appearing and can't display my images

Tags: javascript, function, react-native

I'm trying to stack my images one over the another and will implement swipe( like tinder). but I'm not been able to display my images, instead, I'm just getting a warning,

**Functions are not valid as a react child**

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
  import {StyleSheet, Dimensions, View, Animated, Image } from 'react-native';
  const SCREEN_HEIGHT = Dimensions.get('window').height
  const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width
        //my images
  const Users = [
          { id: "1", uri: require('./assets/image1.jpeg') },
          { id: "2", uri: require('./assets/image2.jpeg') },
          { id: "3", uri: require('./assets/image3.jpeg') },
          { id: "4", uri: require('./assets/image4.jpeg') },
        ]
        export default class App extends Component {
          render() {
//i tried doing this map outside render too , but did not work
            const Images = Users.map((item, i) => {
              return (
                <Animated.View key={item.id} style={{ height: SCREEN_HEIGHT - 120, width: SCREEN_WIDTH, padding: 10, position:'absolute'}}>

                  <Image style={{ flex: 1, height: null, width: null, borderRadius: 20 }} source={item.uri} />

                </Animated.View>
              )
            }
            ).reverse
            return (
              <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={{ height: 60 }}>
                </View>
                <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                {Images} // not getting rendered here
                </View>
                <View style={{ height: 60 }}></View>
              </View>
            );
          }
        }
        //styles
        const styles = StyleSheet.create({
          container: {
            flex: 1,
          }
        });
```

I'm not been able to render my images, it displayed the warning of Functions are not valid as a react child

Comment: Found it: you need `.reverse()` (you basically set `Images` to the `Array.reverse` function instead of its result)

Comment: @ChrisG silly mistake !! thanks buddy . it worked